# "String Does Not Contain Definition For Value"

Tags: c#

I am extracting the value in the app.config for the key of `keyUri` and see this syntax [used by MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx), as well as having used this syntax as well when doing connection strings.  In the below snippet (`System.Configuration` has been added, and the DLL has been added) of C#, I am getting this error:

**C#**

```
/// Error on the .Value
string keyUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyUri"].Value;
```

**app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="keyUri" value="test" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Based on the code, it should be looking within the `<appSettings>`, and returning the value for the key `keyUri`.  Instead, I get an error stating,

> "String Does Not Contain Definition For Value"

Comment: Are you sure the app.config has been copied to the application folder?

Comment: `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[string key]` returns `string`. Just remove `.Value` and you should get "test" in your `keyUri` variable

Comment: The answer is right there in your error message. But you can also consult [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d0bzeeb(v=vs.110).aspx) - `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyUri"]` returns a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx) is a [`NameValueCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx). When you access it [using the index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d0bzeeb.aspx), it returns a `string`. `string` doesn't have a property `Value`, in this case the returned string *is* the value.

So simply omit `.Value`:

```
string keyUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyUri"];
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` stores the data as KeyValuePair, so by specifying the key you will get the value. SO its fine to use like this:

```
string keyUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyUri"]
```

Which means `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyUri"]` will return a string, when you append the `.Value` to this line, you are asking the compiler to get the value property of the string, hence it says *"String Does Not Contain Definition For Value"*. By using the above code you will get the required value in the string variable `keyUri`.

Answer (score 1):

```
string keyUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyUri"];
```

this will give you the result

Comment: What have you changed? Why does this solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's Obvious that there is no property `Value` as other have already mentioned. So you should access it like

```
 string keyUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyUri"];
```

But I think you meant to call the `GetValues()` method like below cause `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` returns a `NameValueCollection`

```
string keyUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("keyUri");
```